# Get current screen dimensions in AwesomeWM

Tags: linux, window-manager, awesome-wm, lua

I want to get the dimensions of the current screen in AwesomeWM. I already studied the AwesomeWM documentation, especially the awesome.screen module (found [here](https://awesomewm.org/doc/api/classes/screen.html#screen.geometry)). However, I still couldn't figure out how to get current screen dimensions in Awesome. I just want to be able to store the current screen width, for example, in a variable called `s_width`.

Note: I use AwesomeWM version 4.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```lua
local s_width = awful.screen.focused().geometry.width
```

Note that "current screen" isn't a thing. Some people argue it is where the mouse pointer is and other argue it is where the focused client is. The `awful.screen.focused()` take optional parameters to let you pick your preferred world view.